# Linear dependence after a linear transformation

Tags: vector-analysis

> Find an example for each of the following, or explain why no example can be found:
>
> a) a linear map $\phi_3 : M_{2\times 2}(\mathbf{R}) \to \mathbf{R}_4$ and matrices $\ell_1, \ldots, \ell_4 \in M_{2\times2}(\mathbf{R})$ that are linearly dependent such that $\phi_3(\ell_1), \ldots, \phi_3(\ell_4)$ are linearly independent.

I believe an example cannot be found for this statement, but what would a proof for this be?

> b) a linear map $\phi_4 : M_{2\times2}(\mathbf{R}) \to \mathbf{R}^4$ and matrices $k_1, \ldots, k_4 \in M_{2\times2}(\mathbf{R})$ that are linearly independent such that $\phi_4(k_1), \ldots, \phi_4(k_4)$ are linearly dependent.

I believe an example for this can be found, my example is
\begin{align*}
m_1 &= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} {1} & {1}\\ {0} & {0} \\\end{smallmatrix} \right) \\
m_2 &= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} {0} & {1}\\ {0} & {0} \\\end{smallmatrix} \right) \\
m_3 &= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} {0} & {0}\\ {1} & {0} \\\end{smallmatrix} \right) \\
m_4 &= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} {0} & {0}\\ {0} & {1} \\\end{smallmatrix} \right)
\end{align*}
This set of matrices is clearly linearly independent, and

$$\phi_4: \left( \begin{smallmatrix} {a} & {b}\\ {c} & {d} \\\end{smallmatrix} \right) \mapsto (a-b,c+d, 2c, 2d)$$

gives $\phi_4(m_1) = (0,0,0,0)$.
So as we already have a 0 vector, it does not matter what $\phi_4(m_2),\phi_4(m_3), \phi_4(m_4)$ are, as we have already attained a 0 vector so any integer multiplied by ϕ(m1) satisfies the condition for linear dependence.

Is this example sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

$l_1,l_2,l_3, l_4$ are linearly dependent

there exists some not trivial set of scalars $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ such that $c_1l_1 + c_2l_2 +c_3l_3 + c_4l_4 = 0$

$\phi(l)$ is a linear map

$\phi(c_1l_1 + c_2l_2 +c_3l_3 + c_4l_4) = c_1\phi(l_1) + c_2\phi(l_2) + c_3\phi(l_3) + c_4\phi(l_4) = 0$

$\phi(l_1),\phi(l_2),\phi(l_3),\phi(l_4)$ are linearly dependent.

2)
Your example seems fine, but you could probably find something even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

A: In general, if $T: V \to W$ is a linear map and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \subset V$ is a linearly dependent set of vectors—i.e., if there exist $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ such that $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0$—then $c_1 T(v_1) + \cdots + c_n T(v_n) = T(c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n) = T(0) = 0$, so $\{c_1 T(v_1), \ldots, c_n T(v_n)\}$ is linearly dependent. So no example can be found.

B: Any set of vectors including the zero vector is trivially linearly dependent, so your example works fine.